# Induction: Confused by trivial proof & upper and lower index

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I am learning induction right now and I am confused by two things.

1. This is a conceptual question, I want to prove a sigma notation using induction. $\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$ (This identity doesn't not matter under this context), is it possible for n to be smaller than i? Like if i starts from 1, can n be 0 in any case?
2. I am confused by the idea of trivial proof and universal quantifiers., I saw this term in the textbook named Discrete Mathematics and Its Application. The questions goes like this:`Find a predicate such that P(1) is False, and $\forall$x$\ge$1(P(k)$\Rightarrow$P(k+1)), and k is a natural number(don't contain 0). In my understanding, I think this proposition is True, mainly because I think if P(1) is False, then this makes the implication True automatically since the hypothesis is False(This is the definition of trivial proof in the textbook described above), so if I just define a predicate like P(n)=$\frac{1}{n-n}$, this will make the hypothesis always False, hence making the implication always True at all possible natural numbers.

Do I misunderstand something here? Really need help. Thanks. :)

Comment: 1. The big sum for $i$ from $0$ to $n$ means $0^2+1^2+ \ldots + n^2$. It means that $n$ must be at least $0$.

Comment: The induction is on $n$. Base case : $n=0$ that means to check if : $0^2 = \dfrac {(0^2+0)(2 \times 0 +1)}{6}$ holdes.

Comment: Yes I got that idea if n is greater than or equal to i, but is it possible for n to be less than i? Just like I said in the description, if i starts from 1, is it possible to n to be 0? Or if i starts from 2, can n be 1?

Comment: The induction step amounts to check if $\sum^n (i^2) + (n+1)^2 = \ldots$ holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I see this doubt has nothing to do with induction itself but with the notation for sums, right? Any way, remeber $\Sigma_{i=0}^n a_i = a_0 + a_1 + \cdots + a_n$. In most cases, you want to evaluate that sum for $n \geq 0$. In case $n < 0 $ (let's say $n = -1$), it is generally accepted that $\Sigma_{i=0}^n a_i = 0$ by definition (as you would by summing from $a_i$ from $i = 0$ to $i = -1$, which doesn't make sense since it's not an increasing sequence).
2. This has more to do with Logic than Discrete Mathematics, indeed. This can be hard to visualize, but since can be false and actually imply some other things. I'm thinking about some trivial example for you to convince yourself, but I can't find any (i'll try later again). 
   Anyway, note $P(n) = \frac{1}{n-n}$ is just a definition and has *no logic value* itself. That is, it's not true or false (although it seems to be lack of logic). Something false would be $1 < 0$ or $a\cdot 0 = a$ $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So for 1. n has to be greater than or equal to i in any case right? Or the other way to say this is that the sequence has to be in increasing order?

Comment: For 2, I read this from that textbook, it says that the universal quantifier is like to prove P(1) and P(2) and ... P(k) is True, k is a natural number. But from logistics, I know an implication is automatically true if the hypothesis is false. So for 2, does that mean I can solve that problem by finding a predicate which has the hypothesis that is always False?

Comment: Note that the actual value of $i$ is chaging while you sum. When you write $\Sigma_{i=m}^n a_i$, then $i$ hold for the summation index, which varies from $m$ to $n$ so in this case the result will be $a_m + \cdots + a_n$ (and note that $i$ is irrelevant for that value, it could have been changed to $j$ or $k$ or whatever, but $m$ and $n$ are precisely defined).

Comment: The words _universal quantifier_ stand for $\forall$ (at least in a vague study), so I really don't get your point. Anyway, you're right saying that $p \implies q$ is true if $p$ is false, so I think the problem could be solved by proposing $P(n): n < 0$ (but that doesn't seem satisfactory at all).

Comment: Yes I am confused by this idea indeed because it looks it's more like a trick instead of math, since that is the easiest way to make $\forall$x$\ge$1(P(k)$\Rightarrow$P(k+1) True

Comment: Just came with an easy example for you to visualize how awesome logic is:

Let's define $P(n) : e^n = e^{n+1}$.

It's obvious, for $n = 1$, that $e^1 \neq e^2$, so $P(1)$ is false.

However, let's suposse $P(n)$. In that case, we accept $e^n = e^{n+1}$. But then $e^{n+1} =_{*_1} e^{n}\cdot e^1 =_{*_2} = e^{n+1}e^1 =_{*_1} = e^{n+2}$, and so we see $P(n+1)$ holds.

(In $*_1$ we've used basic properties of the exponential function, and $*_2$ holds via the hypothesis.)

Comment: This is exactly one of the examples that the exercise asked you about. Note we have been able to prove something holds assuming some other thing which is false. One has to be carefull with those assumptions, since it can be prooven that _anything_ holds supossing something false is true (this is a basic proposition from abstract logic, and it's based in the fact that $P \implies Q$ is true if $P$ is false).

This might be quite disturbing at first (at least it was to me), but you'll get used to the intrisic reasonings of mathematics.

Hope you like it!

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood your task... You are required to provide an *example* of a property that is hereditary (if $P(n)$ is true then $P(n+1)$ is true) but is not universal (because $P(1)$ is not true). This shows that the hereditary is not a sufficient condition to prove a property.

Comment: But if it's possible to find a predicate that has the base case starts from 2 instead of 1? And then prove by induction it is true for all natural number greater than 2?

Comment: @Metaozis Sure, but in that case it is not universal.